# JWT EM JAVA (SPRING BOOT)?

Tags: java, react, spring-boot, jwt

Estou fazendo um projeto, onde tenho um login.
Uso front-end em ReactJS, e backend em Java.
Mas não sei como fazer um token do JWT em java para que no front-end seja efetuado com sucesso o login.

Li este tutorial https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/31/jwts-with-java, baixei ele e o li. Mas ainda estou com dificuldades de entender como adaptar para o meu código!

Aqui está meu código que retorna o login (empresa, usuario e senha)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String Login(@ModelAttribute("empresa") String empresa, 
                    @ModelAttribute("usuario") String usuario,
                    @ModelAttribute("senha") String senha,ModelMap map) throws SQLException {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("PRINTAR O USUARIO >>>"+usuario);
    System.out.println(senha);

    if (usuario.equals("veronica") && senha.equals("123456")) {
        list.add("Sucesso" + usuario);
    } else if (usuario.equals("camila") && senha.equals("123456")) {
        list.add("Sucesso" + usuario);
    } else if (usuario.equals("jose") && senha.equals("123456")) {
        list.add("Sucesso" + usuario);
    } else {
       list.add("Falha no login para a empresa " + empresa + " (usuario ou senha não conferem)");
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonArray = gson.toJson(list);

    map.addAttribute("lists", jsonArray);
    return "main";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você deve escolher uma lib para geração do token JWT, você pode encontrar várias para escolher [aqui](https://jwt.io/).

Para este exemplo irei utilizar a [jjwt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt), escolhi esta versão:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Você precisa de 3 coisas para gerar seu token:

1. O conteúdo para adicionar no token
2. Um secret e um algoritmo para assinar e validar o token
3. A data de expiração do token (na verdade isso é opcional mas que mal faz colocar não é mesmo?)

Você pode adicionar alguns outros detalhes no token também conforme a [especificação do JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519).

#Talk is cheap, show me the code!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String secret = "m3u_s3gr3d0_s3cr3t0"; // Secret para verificação da assinatura do JWT
    final String tokenContent = "meuemail@email.com"; // Conteúdo a ser incluído no JWT
    final Long daysToExpire = 7L;
    final Date expirationDate = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(daysToExpire).atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).toInstant()); // O token irá expirar daqui 7 dias

    String token = Jwts.builder()
                        .setSubject(tokenContent)
                        .setExpiration(expirationDate)
                        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
                        .compact();

    System.out.println(token); // Imprime o token


    String user = Jwts.parser()
                        .setSigningKey(secret)
                        .parseClaimsJws(token)
                        .getBody()
                        .getSubject();

    System.out.println(user); // Imprime meuemail@email.com
}
```

Neste exemplo o output no meu console é este:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtZXVlbWFpbEBlbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1NjQwMDgxODB9.cAt3iTW8LdR2Mmz2KMhMSZwQVhfj9zi-JY29LPToWNXDbQC83IkW4rpXLS60Rs-qqbr-x5lFDpamxELRjblKtA
meuemail@email.com
```

Para verificação do JWT, você deve sempre ter o secret em mãos, neste exemplo podemos validar até no [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existem uma infinidade de algoritmos para assinatura, até mesmo utilizando chaves públicas e privadas.

A idéia então seria então o seu back-end sempre validar o token a cada requisição, passando ele via header por exemplo (que é a idéia do [bearer token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750))